# Printing the height by round of changing object value

Tags: c#, for-loop, return

I am trying to print the height of my object round by round. It starts at a height of 100 Feet. The catch is, it can go either up or down depending on how much energy is spent per turn. I am having a hard time trying to account for instances with I would go beyond 100---the initial starting height. The goal is an asterisk will appear next to the height of the gameObject, rounding down the nearest 10 value;

I've tried incrementing I when the opposite condition is met, but it just floods the console. Perhaps my sense of logic is just completely off here.

```
public void printlocation(Object gameObject)
{
    int heightToPrint = (gameObject.GetHeight() - (gameObject.GetHeight() % 10));

    for (int i = heightToPrint; i >= 0; i -= 10)
    {
        if (i == heightToPrint)   
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{i}m:*");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{i}m:");
        }
    }
}
```

As it stands now it prints asterisks for each iteration of the for loop.

Comment: If you go above 100, then you'll need to change the max value of your scale.  Should it go up to the next nearest 100?  Or will it just stay at 100 and be completely full?  You need to decide...

Comment: Thank you, I was mulling over this in my mind as you posted. I will change the i = 100 to be i = heightToPrint; Then heightToPrint will be the max, or starter value for the for loop, each call. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote `else if (i >= heightToPrint)` instead of `else if (i == heightToPrint)`. Also don't do `i += 10;` in the body of the loop. You are already iterating through all values from 100 down to 0. It makes no difference whether the object moved up or downwards. Just print a "*" at the height it is.

But you can do it easier with

```
public void printlocation(Object gameObject)
{
    int heightToPrint = gameObject.GetHeight() % 10;

    for (int i = 100; i >= 0; i -= 10)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{i}m:{(i == heightToPrint ? "*" : "")}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. that is much cleaner. An additional question, if you don't mind. If during turn number 1, I spend enough energy to propel height greater than my initial value of i=100? To say, instead of i decreasing towards 0, it would go past 100.

Comment: The you will not get any star, since `i == heightToPrint` will always be `false`. You will have to wait until the object gets into the range 0 .. 100.